# Remove old files with specific timings

Tags: python, python-3.x

For several releases, I have this file naming structure:

`release-*<year>_<month>_<build>*`

```
release-v22_06_06.zip
release-v22_06_06
release-changelog-v22_06_06.txt
```

How can I configure python to:

- Keep all files from current month and previous month
- Keep the latest build files from 3 to 4 months ago, so if applicable, remove the other builds in that month
- Remove all release files of 5 months or longer

I started with this code, but I don't know how to match the month in the filename, and then 'substract' 2 months from it.

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import glob
from datetime import datetime

release_files = glob.glob("/tmp/release*")
month = datetime.now().date().month

for item in release_files:
  file_month = item.split("_")
  if '8' in file_month[1]:
    print(item)
```

Comment: split the name, from splited time data make datetime object, then do all run/condition on this object and if follow condition then delete the file\

Answer (score 0):

Comparing only months is nice as long you are staying within a year.
In general I would recommend working with datetime objects, though.

```
date_string = filename[-12:-4] # extracting the date_substring
dt = datetime.strptime(date_string,'%y_%m_%d') # converting to datetime

if datetime.now() - dt > datetime.timedelta(days=60): # timedelta unfortunately doesn't have a month field
# do something
```

Comment: So this would break January 2023?

Answer (score -1):

You can use regex method

https://regex101.com/r/2e37k2/2/

```py
import re

pattern = "(\d{2})"

filename = "release-changelog-v22_06_06.txt"

x = re.findall(pattern, filename)

print(x)

x = ['22', '06', '06']
```